# BizTalk Schema development Could not find schema information for the element

Tags: xsd, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-deployment

Please find the below sample XML format, for which I'm trying to build a schema's on BizTalk Solution.

**I was receiving the warning messages as**

> warning BEC2004: Could not find schema information for the element 'ORX'.
> warning BEC2004: Could not find schema information for the element 'NONSIGNONMSGSRQV1'.
> warning BEC2004: Could not find schema information for the element 'NONSONRQ'.
> warning BEC2004: Could not find schema information for the element 'CLIENT'.
> warning BEC2004: Could not find schema information for the element 'ID'.
> warning BEC2004: Could not find schema information for the element 'USERPASS'.
> etc..
> .....
> .....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?ORX ORXHEADER="200" VERSION="201" SECURITY="NONE" OLDFILEUID="NONE" NEWFILEUID="NONE" ?>
<ORX>
  <NONSIGNONMSGSRQV1>
    <NONSONRQ>
      <CLIENT>123456765</CLIENT>
      <ID>arout_int</ID>
      <USERPASS>IM_Developer</USERPASS>
      <LANGUAGE>ENG</LANGUAGE>
      <APPID>WASSUP</APPID>
      <APPOVER>1</APPOVER>
    </NONSONRQ>
  </NONSIGNONMSGSRQV1> 
  <NONVERMSGSRQV1>
    <NONEMPLOYERHISTTRNRQ>
      <COOKIE>1234576540</COOKIE>
      <COOKIETAN>12345612340</COOKIETAN> 
      <BILLINGO1>45674567890</BILLINGO1> 
      <BILLINGO2>1245673567890</BILLINGO2> 
      <PURPOSE>
        <CODE>PROGRAM</CODE>
      </PURPOSE> 
      <EMPLOYERHISTRQ>
        <EMPLOYEEID>123004567</EMPLOYEEID>
      </EMPLOYERHISTRQ>
  </NONEMPLOYERHISTTRNRQ>
  </NONVERMSGSRQV1>
</ORX>
```

After I did some Googling, I got some knowledge from the link  [Validating XML Instance having issues](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/04764762-0362-4f33-a6ce-5e15ad5bf3c9/validating-xml-instance-having-issues?forum=biztalkgeneral) I tried to remove target name space of Schema properties, but BizTalk solutions is not allowing to remove the targetnamespace, which is already there for the schema.

Please could any one suggest me, how could I apply that settings to my XML schema development, as my XML document doesn't have targetnamespace?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by reading [BizTalk 2006 Recipes: A Problem-Solution Approach](http://books.google.com/books?id=tvzUW4pnoDwC&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=xsd%20xml%20tutorial%20biztalk&source=bl&ots=KLSOjIr68e&sig=EQgXvBBBX-7eGQvXiHpDPJr9zeQ&hl=en&ei=4YF8SqadM6ewtgfnj_njAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1#v=onepage&q&f=false),

Steps: Open the schema -> Goto Schema Node -> Schema node properties -> remove the namespace, then solved the problem.